# How to add and link multiple html's in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to add a page `settings.html` to my chrome extension to keep the `popup.html`as clean as possible with only a few buttons. All settings should be done in a seperated popup called `settings.html`.

I have added a `settings-btn` which should link to the `settings.html` file.
On the `settings.html` I have a button called `'back-btn'` which then should link back to the `popup.html` after the user has done all settings.

I tried to open it like this from my `popup.js` (my main GUI):

```
let settingsButton = document.getElementById('settings-btn');

settingsButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: 'settings.html' });
});
```

But that is doing nothing.

What would be the correct way to use more than one "popup" in a chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking way  to complicated. A simple href is enough.

Comment: Just to add to this: yes, any extension HTML page can be opened as a tab, by itself, e.g. `chrome.tabs.create({url: 'settings.html'});` or href